# How to use bullet symbol to display as output?

Tags: java, android, char, spannablestring, spannable

I used by coping the bullet symbol and placed in char symbol. But problem is it's displaying the bullet symbol with [such blue color](https://emoji.fileformat.info/gemoji/arrow_forward.png) in mobile. My Requirement is, it should be [black arrow](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/black_rightpointing_triangle.png) .

Here is my code:

```
 Spannable spannable = SpanUtils.createNestingParagraphsSpannable(strings,
'▶', mFirstLineIndent); //but this is not working as expected output.



 public static Spannable createNestingParagraphsSpannable(List<String> paragraphs,
                                                             char bulletSymbol, int indent) {

        List<ImprovedPair<Integer, Integer>> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int count = CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(paragraphs).size();
        for (int i = 0, last = count - 1; i < count; ++i) {
            int start = builder.length();
            if (i > 0) {
                builder.append(bulletSymbol); //here I am using the bullet symbol
                builder.append(" ");
            }

            builder.append(paragraphs.get(i));

            if (i < last) {
                builder.append("\n\n");
            }

            indexes.add(new ImprovedPair<>(start, builder.length()));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using unicode of bullet Symbol instead of symbol itself.
like:-

```
char bulletSymbol='\u2023';
```

Comment: Hello @Tarun I replaced this. But it's displaying the numbers. \u2023 instead of symbol. builder.append("\u2023")

Answer (score 4):

try replacing your '▶' with "\u2023"

This is the unicode for the symbol you are after.
By placing this unicode in a string or a char will insert the symbol when it is printed